# Improper zip entries when writing filename containing non-English characters even with Java 7

Tags: java, zip, special-characters, java-7

I am trying to develop code that can handle zipping files with non-English characters (Umlaut, Arabic etc) but the zipped file contains improper names. I am using **java version 1.7.0_45** thus it shouldn't be due to the bug mentioned [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4244499).I am setting the charset to UTF-8 for the `ZipOutputStream` constructor and as per Javadocs it should work as per my requirements.

I am assured that the zip file is being written correctly as an attempt to read entries from the file gives proper filenames (as expected).

However, when I try to open/extract with either Ubuntu default ArchiveManager/Unzip tool, the filenames are messed up.

Here is my code :

```
private void convertFilesToZip(List<File> files) {
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("zipFile.zip");

        ZipOutputStream outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        for (File file : files) {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            String filename = file.getName();
            System.out.println("Adding file : " + filename);
            outputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(filename));

            int length;

            while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            outputStream.closeEntry();
        }

        if(inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("Zip created successfully");
        System.out.println("=======================================================");
        System.out.println("Reading zip Entries");
        ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("zipFile.zip")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        while((zipEntry=zipInputStream.getNextEntry())!=null){
            System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        }

        zipInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the output for the files is as follows:

```
Adding file : umlaut_ḧ.txt
Adding file : ذ ر ز س ش ص ض.txt
Adding file : äǟc̈ḧös̈ ẗǚẍŸ_uploadFile4.txt
Adding file : pingüino.txt
Adding file : ÄÖÜäöüß- Español  deEspaña.ppt
Zip created successfully
=======================================================
Reading zip Entries
umlaut_ḧ.txt
ذ ر ز س ش ص ض.txt
äǟc̈ḧös̈ ẗǚẍŸ_uploadFile4.txt
pingüino.txt
ÄÖÜäöüß- Español  deEspaña.ppt
```

Has anyone successfully implemented what I wish to achieve here.
Can someone point me to what I may have missed or have been doing wrong.I did all the google I could and even tried `Apache Commons Compress` but still no luck.

It's mentioned in the bug report that the bug is resolved in Java 7, then why is the code not working.

Comment: Are you sure that the Unzip tool that you are using is able to handle the characters in your filenames?

Comment: yes it is. As mentioned, both default ubuntu archive manager and unzip tool are able to separately zip/unzip the files. But, the file created  by my code has names messed up.

Comment: I have come across a workaround where I am using `ProcessBuilder` to create the zip. But, it is not a very efficient way. Has anyone been able to resolve it with java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Update]
I finally figured out that the problem is not in the code but is in fact with the default ArchiveManager of Ubuntu. It doesn't recognizes/extracts the contents properly. When the same file is opened/extracted by the windows zip handler, it works flawlessly.

Additionally, the commons-compress supports a bunch of other formats too apart from the zip,gzip supported by Java.

`http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/index.html`